# How to solve , has no member function "print" in case of conditional base class using metaprogramming

Tags: c++, inheritance, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

.header

```
template<class T>
struct type_is
{
 using type = T; 
};

template<bool, class T, class>
struct IF_t : type_is<T> {};

template<class T, class F>
struct IF_t<false, T, F> : type_is<F> {};

class Base1
{
public:
void print()
{
    std::cout << "Base 1" << std::endl;
}
};

class Base2
{
public:
void print()
{
    std::cout << "Base 2" << std::endl;
}
};

template <int q>
class Derived : IF_t<(q > 0), Base1, Base2>
{
};

class MultipleBaseTemplateMetaProg {
public:
void print()
{
    Derived<1> aDerivedTrue;
    aDerivedTrue.print();
    Derived<-1> aDerivedFalse;
    aDerivedFalse.print();
}
};
```

Main.cpp

```
 MultipleBaseTemplateMetaProg aMetaProg;
 aMetaProg.print();
```

My problem is, when I try to call print(). I get error saying the print is not a member function. I cannot use "using" as well in the Derived class to declare the print.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Apart from creating a common base class?

Answer (score 5):

Try replacing `class Derived : IF_t<...>` with `class Derived : public IF_t<...>::type`. `Derived` is deriving from the `IF_t` rather than either `Base1` or `Base2`. It also needs to be public so you can access `Base1`/`Base2` functions from a `Derived`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the implementation of your conditional type. Changing it to this

```
template<bool, class T, class>
struct IF_t : public T {}; 

template<class T, class F>
struct IF_t<false, T, F> : public F {};
```

causes it to build (once you change all the derivations to `public` in the following - another mistake, incidentally).

Note that there is already [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional).

---

Fully building code:

```
#include <iostream>


template<class T>
struct type_is
{
using type = T;                                                                                                                                                                                          
};  

template<bool, class T, class>
struct IF_t : public T {}; 

template<class T, class F>
struct IF_t<false, T, F> : public F {}; 

class Base1
{   
public:
void print()
{   
    std::cout << "Base 1" << std::endl;
}   
};  

class Base2
{   
public:
void print()
{   
    std::cout << "Base 2" << std::endl;
}   
};  

template <int q>
class Derived : public IF_t<(q > 0), Base1, Base2>
{   
};  

class MultipleBaseTemplateMetaProg {
public:
void print()
{   
    Derived<true> aDerivedTrue;
    aDerivedTrue.print();
    Derived<false> aDerivedFalse;
    aDerivedFalse.print();
}   
};  


int main()
{   
MultipleBaseTemplateMetaProg aMetaProg;
aMetaProg.print();
}
```

Comment: This leads to `Derived` being directly derived from `IF_t<...>` which derived from `Base1` or `Base2`. `IF_t` should just be a helper struct.

Comment: Thanks, @Kevin - In any case, I think that the first three (or so) classes here are redundant - `std::conditional` should be used. If it is not, can't say I really see the difference of using a standard library convention (such as `type`) without the standard library itself.

Comment: @AmiTavory Thanks for your response!  I put this specifically because I will be using an Enum instead of a Bool. As I will have more than 2 Base classes and multiple specializations.... if you see any other way to tackle let me know! One more thing, I am restricted to C++03

Comment: @user3801185 You're welcome. I think that the question of choosing a type with one of several options (your enum) is a very interesting problem. I'd suggest that you 1. open a question specifically asking about that, and 2. make sure to tag it as c++03. I'm sure people will be happy to answer. If you drop here a note, I'll be happy to look at it too.